# php get specific json objects

Tags: php, json, parameters

So I was about to obtain url from google custom search and I built parameter as search query but, it just shows blank page to me.

It was supposed to be localhost/1.php?search_query=computer

Here is the json data:

```
  "items": [
    {
      "link": "https://www.ebay.com/b/Computers-Tablets-Network-Hardware/58058/bn_1865247"
    }
  ]
}
```

I wanna obtain the "link" field

Here is my code:

```
<?php
function getStatus($id){
    if ($id == "") {
        $data['message'] = "Please input the search query";
        $data['message'] = "null";
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else{
        $get = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDgzVDNV0q2EZznyyHPy9MK_JHjXhMHqt8&cx=baf729f2156aad895&q=".$id."&num=1&fields=items(link)");
        $json = json_decode($get,true);
        $data[“ebay_link”] = $json["items"]["link"];
        
        return $data;
    }
   
}
$query = $_GET['search_query'];
    $statusFinal = getStatus($query);
    echo json_encode($statusFinal);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the index link is inside another dimension so it'll be `[items][0][link]`. be careful with the smart quotes `“ebay_link”` they aren't really that smart

Comment: Also, you overwrite `$data['message']` before displaying your message.

Comment: @Kevin oh yeah my bad it's working now. thanks

Comment: Here is the result https:\/\/www.ebay.com\/b\/Computers-Tablets-Network-Hardware\/58058\/bn_1865247 is there a way to regex it? I don't know well about regex

Comment: @ObsidianAge oh yeah didn't notice that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very new to Stack Overflow. So sorry if some things are a bit confusing or some terms are wrong. Here's what I think you're looking for.

```php
<?php

function getStatus($id){
    if ($id == "") {
        $data['message'] = "Please input the search query";
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else{
        $get = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDgzVDNV0q2EZznyyHPy9MK_JHjXhMHqt8&cx=baf729f2156aad895&q=".$id."&num=1&fields=items(link)");
        $json = json_decode($get,true);
        $data['ebay_link'] = $json["items"][0]["link"];
        
        return $data;
    }
   
}
    $beatmapId = $_GET['search_query'];
    $statusFinal = getStatus($beatmapId);
    echo json_encode($statusFinal, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

?>
```

The first change was removing `$data['message'] = "null";` as I didn't think it was needed. Add it back if it was actually needed. Then, decided to change `$data[“ebay_link”]` to `$data['ebay_link']`. After that, changed `$data['ebay_link'] =` to `$json["items"][0]["link"]` to go inside by a dimension. Lastly, added `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` when encoding to JSON so you wouldn't get backslashes.